# Groovy WithWriter method with explicitly given character encoding destroys specific chars

Tags: file-io, encoding, groovy

I read a file encoded in Windows-1250. I read each line into a list, then do some append operations and store the collection into a new file.

Problem. If I write explicitly encoding, then the output file appear to be badly encoded. If I do not set any encoding, output is OK.

```
enrichedFile.withWriter("windows-1250") { out ->
     tempFinalList.each() { line ->
          out.println line
     } 
}
```

=> bad output

```
enrichedFile.withWriter { out ->
     tempFinalList.each() { line ->
         out.println line
     }
}
```

=> OK.

FYI: I use it for czech language with letters as: ěščřžýáíé.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see there is any problem.

```
def myFile = new File('./Archive/file.txt')
def tempFinalList = []

//Reading from the file with windows charset
myFile.withReader('windows-1250') { out ->
    out.eachLine{
        tempFinalList << it
    }
}

//Appending stuff
tempFinalList << 'a' << 'b'

//Creating a new file
def newFile = new File('./Archive/NewFile.txt')

//Writing to the new file with windows charset
newFile.withWriter('windows-1250'){out ->
    tempFinalList.each{out.writeLine it}
}

newFile.eachLine{println it}
```

Where content of `file.txt` contains czech characters you have mentioned.

Output from the last line:

```
ešcržýáíé
ešcržýáíé
ešcržýáíé
ešcržýáíé
ešcržýáíé
a
b
```